# Mint linut: shutdown script using zenity not working

Tags: linux-mint, shutdown, zenity

I wrote a simple script which runs when I'm shutting down my computer. I placed the script under `/etc/init.d/` directory and link it back to `/etc/rc0.d/`. The link is soft link and its name is `K99checkout-reminder`.

Here's the result from listing files under `/etc/rc0.d/`:

`lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    24 Nov 17 18:10 K99checkout-reminder -> ../init.d/alert_checkout`

Here's the content of `alert_checkout`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0.0
if zenity --question --text="I guess you have a nice working day?"; then
    zenity --info --text="Gr8! Now please
          _______

               |
               |
               |
               v

DO NOT forget to CHECKOUT your working time at door.\n\nSee you next day!"
else
    zenity --info --text="Thats really sad.\n\nGo checkout your time to finish your working.\n\nHave good dinner, go sleep early and have a nice day!"
fi
```

I tried to run the script under `root` privilege and it works fine:

```
$ /etc/rc0.d $ sudo ./K99checkout-reminder
```

Got an alert box appeared!

Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the owner maybe if it works after that its a permissions thing. Permissions can be tricky even if given full access sometimes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try to add \ symbol before line endings in the zenity text, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0.0
if zenity --question --text="I guess you have a nice working day?"; then
zenity --info --text="Gr8! Now please \
      _______\
\
               |\
               |\
               |\
               v\
\
DO NOT forget to CHECKOUT your working time at door.\n\nSee you next day!";
else
zenity --info --text="Thats really sad.\n\nGo checkout your time to finish your         working.\n\nHave good dinner, go sleep early and have a nice day!"
fi
```

or replace new line symbols with \n escapes.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there's a difference between *running under root privileges* and *running under the `root` user*. If you tried to run it like this:

`sudo ./alert_checkout`

then it worked, becouse the **Real UID** was still set to your user, with only the **Effective UID** being changed to root. However, when running as a `init.d` script, it is executed **under the root user**, so both UIDs are set to **root**.

This is consfusing for `zenity` as it needs to display the message inside your user sesssion. Therefore it needs the Real ID to match your user.

If you only need this to work for a particular user account, then simply edit the script and run zenity under `su <user> -c <zenity cmd>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the link you are showing is a symbolic link or symlink.

When the system is shutting down, I think it runs the Kill inits in Numerical order, so that

K01... is run before k02...

If you are running this script as K99...

Then wouldn't the window manager already be shut down?

Have you tried running your script as:

```
K01checkout-reminder
```